# LocalBroadcastManager, android:process=":ProcessName", Too much ram usage

Tags: android, memory, memory-management, process, hardware-acceleration

Alright so I'm going to try to explain one problem at a time so you can understand the issues I'm having and hopefully someone will be able to tell me hoe to fix it. So my app runs perfectly but my users have been complaining of high ram usage and on average it runs any where from 120mb to 200mb IDLE which I agree isn't right so I went ahead and remembered a trick I used in a previous project and that was this line of code android:hardwareAccelerated="false". This removes about 10mb of ram per activity but I'm still sitting at about 90mb of usage so i went and looked a little harder and found this android:process=":ProcessName"> which takes my app from using 100mb to a mere 8mb of ram. But I'm facing a problem while doing this and that is the fact that I have a LocalBroadcastManager in a service activity that sends data to my MainActivity and when these two have different processes they don't communicate with each other, and if I combine them into the same process the usage spikes yet again. So I'm kinda stuck what to do at this point and I refuse to use the Android Memory debugger because it doesn't tell me jack crap about what my code is doing wrong. Quite literally I have 5 text views and an imageview inside of my MainActivity so I know its not that intensive by any means! If anyone needs code please let me know but I figured someone really didn't need to look at the code to answer this!

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

> But I'm facing a problem while doing this and that is the fact that I have a LocalBroadcastManager in a service activity that sends data to my MainActivity and when these two have different processes they don't communicate with each other, and if I combine them into the same process the usage spikes yet again.

You can keep your Service in a separate process and bind to it from your app's first process, via IPC, inter-process communication.

See:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html

There are different ways to do IPC. The `Messenger` option might be a good starting point for you:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Messenger

From the documentation:

> If you need your service to communicate with remote processes, then you can use a Messenger to provide the interface for your service. This technique allows you to perform interprocess communication (IPC) without the need to use AIDL.